# How to inject mock object in spy object?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I have to test a rest api in spring application which has dependency on service class and it also has dependency on dao class. I have created controller instance with `@InjectMocks`, service with `@Spy` and dao with `@Mock`. In my current scenario, the api that I'm testing calls a method in within spy and the called method calls a method in mock. If I don't use spy then the test doesn't work properly and if used then the instance of dao is not injected into service. In this context what should I need to do inject mocked object of dao into spy object?

Comment: Are you trying to unit test the controller code?

Comment: yes! I'm trying to verify that dao instance is called through service instance while accessing rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks` in service  class, but it can work's incorrectly.
I think best practice it separate your test. You can write one test for `rest api` and create mock from service and second test for service.